# Please explain to me why this does not assign a copy, but a pointer? C#

Tags: c#, console

This is the program in question:

```
namespace TestStuff
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int x;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test firstClass = new Test();
            firstClass.x = 5;
            Test secondClass = firstClass;
            firstClass.x = 6;
            Console.WriteLine(secondClass.x);

        }
    }
}
```

The output of this program is 6, I assume this is because `Test secondClass = firstClass;`, makes secondClass point to firstClass instead of making a copy of firstClass. If i want to make secondClass a copy of firstClass, how would I go about that ?

Answer (score -1):

I guess it's an OOP (Object-Oriented Programming) misconception. Although `Test.x` is an `int` (thus a value type) and, if copied around, you wouldn't get a reference for it, in this case, you're copying the whole `Test` instance from `firstClass` to `secondClass`.

`Test secondClass = firstClass;` will make both "references" being the same object and by modifying `firstClass.x` you'll also update `secondClass.x`. It's not because of `.x`, but because `firstClass` and `secondClass` are both the same instance of object.

> If i want to make secondClass a copy of firstClass, how would I go about that?

In order to achieve this, you need to clone the object, instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/129395/1256062 might be a good source for it.

Comment: And how does this answer "how to copy the object"?

Comment: OP has already discovered this.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I've added the answer a few seconds later, when just realized it. It was also already flagged as duplicated.

Comment: I'm trying to address @victorfaarvang misconception and not just the last phase in his question.